# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-cli

I am using a Firestorage / Firebase tutorial project from [Github](https://github.com/martinakraus/KittyGramUpload).
The project description is [here](https://dev.to/angular/implement-file-upload-with-firebase-storage-in-our-angular-app-the-simple-way-1ofi).

It seems to be well-designed, so I guess the problem is my own ignorance.

After logging it with my GMail credentials, I experience the following error, and my avatar image is not shown:

```
Initiator: platform-browser.js:1213
GET https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-vz7Fxnqe9Mo/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AMZuucnJJZ_Itph8fgRsQrR9saxjY1RytQ/s96-c/photo.jpg
Error 403
```

This happens when I want to show the user's GMail avatar.

I can navigate to this image even in an incognito browser window, so I don't understand why my app can't display it.

I think it's not related to Firestorage, but I will post my Firestorage rules here anyway:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

I am running the project locally on http://localhost:4200/

In Firebase, I have "localhost" in the list of Authorised domains.

What could I check to track down the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that localhost doesn't work here.

Once deployed on my server, it worked fine.

Would be nice to know what the problem is though.